# Relationship between "Radial" Fourier transform and Fourier transform, especially at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function with compact support.

What is the relationship between

$$
\widehat{\phi}(k) = \int e^{-2\pi i x \cdot k} \phi(x) dx, \quad k \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$

and

$$
\widetilde{\phi}(\ell) = \int e^{-2\pi i |x| \ell} \phi(x) dx, \quad \ell \in \mathbb{R}
$$

In particular, I would like to know what I can say about $\widehat{\phi}(k)$ if I know that $\limsup_{\ell \to \infty} |\widetilde{\phi}(\ell)| > 0$.

Edit:

In my attempt to simplify a problem, I have simplified it too much. As Willie Wong has pointed out, $\limsup_{\ell \to \infty} |\widetilde{\phi}(\ell)| > 0$ is never satisfied for $\phi$ smooth and compactly supported.

I'm actually interested in the situation where $\phi(x)dx$ is replaced by $d\mu(x)$, where it is indeed possible to have $\limsup_{\ell \to \infty} |\widetilde{\phi}(\ell)| > 0$.

Comment: Write $\psi(r) = \int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} \phi(r\omega) d\omega$, you have that $\tilde{\phi}(\ell) = \int_0^\infty e^{-2\pi i r \ell} \psi(r) r^{n-1} dr$. Extend $\psi(r)$ to be zero for $r \leq 0$. Then the function $\psi(r) r^{n-1}$ is by definition $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. By Riemann-Lebesgue you must have $\lim_{\ell\to \infty} \tilde{\phi}(\ell) = 0$. So your assumption that the limsup is positive is vacuous.

Comment: You're right. In my attempt to simplify the problem, I have simplified it too much. I'm actually interested in the situation where $\phi(x) dx$ is replaced by $d\mu(x)$, where it is indeed possible to have $\limsup_{\ell \to \infty}|\widetilde{\phi}(\ell)| > 0.$

Comment: I do not think the two have much in common: if $\mu$ is the uniform measure on the sphere, then $\tilde\phi$ oscillates, but $\hat\phi$ converges to zero. If $\mu$ is the uniform measure on the boundary of a hyper-cube, then $\tilde\phi$ converges to zero, but $\hat\phi$ oscillates in cardinal directions.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki: I think your comment should be _the_ answer. Given that $\tilde{\phi}$ is only sensitive to the spherical symmetric part of $\mu$, what you wrote pretty succinctly captures the difference.

Answer (score 2):

(A comment turned into an answer, following Willie Wong's suggestion).

I do not think the two have much in common. If $\mu$ is the uniform measure on the sphere, then $\tilde\phi$ oscillates, but $\hat\phi$ converges to zero. On the other hand, if $\mu$ is the uniform measure on the boundary of a hyper-cube, then $\tilde\phi$ converges to zero, but $\hat\phi$ oscillates in cardinal directions.

Comment: Would you mind outlining the calculation for the behaviour of $\widetilde{\phi}$ that you assert?

Comment: For the hyper-cube case, after integrating in the angular directions, $\tilde{\phi}$ is essentially the Fourier transform of an $L^1$ function (since the cube is not spherically symmetric the measure smears out on integration in angular directions), and the convergence follow from Riemann-Lebesgue. In the sphere case, $\tilde{\phi}$ is essentially the Fourier transform of the point mass. @MichaelGaudreau

Comment: @WillieWong I have this intuition that oscillation of $\widetilde{\phi}$ should slow down the decay of $\widehat{\phi}$. For example, the Fourier transform of Lebesgue measure on a solid ball, $\widehat{\lambda}$, has very rapid Fourier decay. And $\widetilde{\lambda}$ also decays. But the Fourier transform of the spherical measure, $\widehat{\sigma}$, only decays like $|x|^{-(n+1)/2}$, and  $\widetilde{\, \sigma }$ doesn't decay at all. So it would seem like non-decay of $\widetilde{\mu}$ is an obstacle to the decay of $\widehat{\mu}$ somehow. Continued in next.

Comment: @WillieWong One could imagine an intermediate scenario where $\mu$ is a measure on a union of concentric spheres whose radii form a Cantor set. If it's the middle thirds Cantor set, then $\widetilde{\mu}$ will not decay at all. Then, based on this intuition that non-decay of  $\widetilde{\mu}$ is an obstacle to the decay of $\widehat{\mu}$, I would expect $\widehat{\mu}$ to decay no faster than $\widehat{\sigma}$ does. That's the kinda of relationship I was hoping for. Do you think I should edit the original question?

Comment: @MichaelGaudreau: Your question seems to be related to Fourier (and Hausdorff) dimension of measures. I know next to nothing about this; [these lecture notes](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/actividades/congresos/cimpa2017/course-notes-mattila.pdf) (and the corresponding [book](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781316227619)) seem to give a good entry point to the literature.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thanks for the references. I see there is definitely a connection there. I have even looked through the book you suggested before, but the relationship I'm after doesn't seem to be mentioned. 
Would you suggest I ask a second question on MO? I realize this one wasn't precise enough.

Comment: To put things another way, I'm looking for a kind of ``product'' decomposition of $\widehat{\mu}$ in terms of $\widetilde{\mu}$. The disintegration formula gives $\widehat{\mu}(k) = \int_{(0,\infty)} \int_{S_r}  e^{-2\pi i k \cdot x} d\mu_r(x) d\nu(r) = \int_{(0,\infty)} \widehat{\mu_r}(k) d\nu(r)$ where $\nu$ is the pushforward of $\mu$ under the map $x \mapsto |x|$ and $\mu_r$ are measures living on $S_r$, the sphere of radius $r$. That's somewhat close, but $\widetilde{\mu}$ doesn't just pop out here. Continued in next.

Comment: I'm not so good with stationary phase, but I thought that maybe $\widehat{\mu_r}(k)$ has an asymptotic expansion with an oscillating factor like $e^{i |k| r}$ that I could use to get the Fourier transform of $\widehat{\nu} = \widetilde{\mu}$.

Comment: For functions at least, you can take spherical harmonic expansions. For the spherical harmonic of a fix degree, its Fourier transform has well-known formulas in terms of integration of the radial component against Bessel functions. See sections IV.3 and IV.4 in Stein and Weiss, _Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces_.

Comment: @MichaelGaudreau: for spherically symmetric functions supported away from the origin, using the asymptotic bounds on the Bessel functions, you can expect that the leading order term of $\hat{\phi}(k)$ to be given by $|k|^{- (n-1)/2}$ times the $\tilde{\psi}(|k|)$, where $\psi(x) = \phi(x) / |x|^{(n-1)/2}$.// The case of the hypercube is one where the higher spherical harmonics add up to have bigger contribution than the spherical component.

Comment: @WillieWong I guess the point is that $\mu_r$ is not necessarily spherically symmetric (and not necessarily a function). I appreciate the references though.

Comment: @WillieWong The point about spherical harmonic expansions sounds like it is worth considering.

Comment: @MichaelGaudreau: If $\nu$ is a rotationally invariant measure that assigns equal measure to centred balls as $\mu$ does, then the decay of $\hat\mu$ is no faster than the decay of $\hat\nu$. So your question boils down to the following univariate one: how fast can the Hankel transform of a measure $r^{n-1} \rho(dr)$ on $(0, \infty)$ go to zero at infinity given certain decay rate of the Fourier transform of $\rho$. Since the Bessel function is close to a trigonometric function, I suppose the Hankel transform cannot really behave any better, but I did not attempt to work out the details.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki I'm not quite sure I follow. Your $\nu$ is not the same $\nu$ that I introduced above. That's fine. But what is the relationship between $\mu$, $\nu$, and $\rho$? I don't see how you are making the asserted reduction. Could you please explain?

Comment: @MichaelGaudreau: $\rho$ was supposed to be given by $\rho([0,r)) = \mu(B(0,r))$, but I think I messed up the exponents: there seems to be even less relation than I initially thought.